# How to make an IntegrationFlow with transform?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to take records from the database and transform it to json. This runs on Spring Cloud Dataflow.

I suspect I am missing some call on the IntegrationFlow.

The error output is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:440)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:319)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:267)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:140)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)


@Bean
public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource() {
    String query = "select cd_int_controle, de_tabela from int_controle rowlock readpast " +
    "where id_status = 0 order by cd_int_controle";
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter =
    new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, query);

    adapter.setMaxRows(properties.getPollSize());
    adapter.setUpdatePerRow(true);
    adapter.setRowMapper((RowMapper<IntControle>) (rs, i) -> new IntControle(rs.getLong(1), rs.getString(2)));
    adapter.setUpdateSql("update int_controle set id_status = 1 where cd_int_controle = :cdIntControle");

    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jsonSupplier() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(properties.getPollRateMs(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).transactional()))
            .transform((GenericTransformer<List<IntControle>, String>) ints -> {
                //transform to Json
            })
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing several points:

1. The `transform()` in the Spring Integration indeed requires an output channel or reply channel header. There is just no way in Spring Integration to bypass channels between endpoints. Even if it is not requested in your flow between JDBC and transform, it is present there by the framework anyway. Since you call `get()` in the end of the flow and don't provide any hints what channel send transform result to, such a `DestinationResolutionException` is thrown.
2. Spring Cloud Stream functional model deals with basic Java interfaces - `Supplier`, `Function` & `Consumer`. Calling a bean as `jsonSupplier` doesn't make it as a `Supplier`. You really need to say the framework what bean to use for binding. See docs for more info: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function

So, you are missing a connection point between an `IntegrationFlow` and `Supplier` declaration. Probably this one could work for you:

```
@Bean
PollableChannel jsonChannel() {
   return new QueueChannel();
}

...
          .transform((GenericTransformer<List<IntControle>, String>) ints -> {
                //transform to Json
          })
          .channel(jsonChannel())
          .get();
...

@Bean
public Supplier<Message<?>> jsonSupplier() {
    return jsonChannel()::receive;
}
```

So, the idea is to dump result of the flow into some channel and then bridge that data from a `Supplier` which is already visible for Spring Cloud Stream binding logic.

See also here: https://sagan-production.cfapps.io/blog/2019/10/25/spring-cloud-stream-and-spring-integration

Comment: with you guidance I have managed to make IntegrationFlow work, but now the supplier function is never called. I have `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.jsonSupplier-out-0=output` and `spring.cloud.function.definition=jsonSupplier` on my configuration.

Comment: Do you have a binder dependency? Probably Spring Cloud Stream is just not fired up because there is no a binder dependency in your project...

Comment: ```<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>```

Comment: OK. Did you debug it to be sure that your supplier is not called? Any chances to share with us a simple `source` application project to let us to reproduce an issue?

Comment: Does jsonSupplier needs to be annotated with @PollableBean ?

Comment: No, because it doesn’t produce a `Flux`

Comment: I have put a logger on te queue channel and it's being called (thru receive) but the following flow `stream create --name sybase_to_pgsql --definition "jdbc-sybase-supplier | log "` does not output any log.

Comment: Have no idea. Sounds like a separate, more DataFlow-specific SO question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211414/spring-cloud-dataflow-does-not-flow